# WooCommerce Memberships: Conditional to check a page access

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, woocommerce-memberships

I have a Wordpress Memberships website that is built on WooCommerce with WooCommerce Memberships plugin to restrict certain pages to members only.

Some of those pages are "drip-fed"... ie. Access to those pages opens 3 days after purchase, etc. I have set this up in WooMemberships.

I am trying to simply do a PHP conditional check to see if the current user has access to a certain page.

I have found this code piece in the docs: `wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted()`

However, I have been unable to make it work.

Is there a code snippet which will basically do a PHP IF statement on whether the current user has access to a certain page (using `page ID`)?

eg:

```
if ( current_user_has_access(page_ID) ) { DO SOMETHING } else { DON'T }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to Replace (in the conditions):

1. `$page_id` by your `page ID` number (for example: is_page(42))
2. `$membership_plan` by the slug of the plan (`'plan_slug'`) or related `post ID`.

The conditions:

- `wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted($page_id)` => `true` if `$page_id` is retracted.
- `is_page($page_id)` => true if is actual `$page_id`.
- `wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $membership_plan )` => `true` actual user is an active member for this `$membership_plan` plan. In that case the access to the page is granted by the suscription plan of the user.

You can remove some of the conditions, if not needed, and fine tune for your needs.

```
if( wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted() && is_page($page_id) && wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $membership_plan ) ) {

    // do something

} else {

    // don't

}
```

---

--- Update ---

The only function related to restriction and (or) time access are:

1) `wc_memberships_restrict( $content, $membership_plans, $delay, $exclude_trial  )`
 just like shortcode `[wcm_restrict]` (so not useful)…

2) `wc_memberships_get_user_access_time( $user_id, $target, $action, $gmt )`: Parameters

```
$user_id  // for a logged 'user ID'
$target   : array('post' => id, 'product' => id) // content_type and content_id
$action   : 'view' or 'purchase' // Type of access (products only)<br>
$gmt =>   : true  or  false // (selection of the time zone)
// Returns user access start timestamp (in site timezone) for content or a product
```

---

Reference: [**WooCommerce Memberships Function Reference**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-function-reference/)

Comment: That is amazing thank you. I've tried it out, and it is confirming that the user is a member, etc - however it is saying they have access to pages that they should not have access to until X days have passed...     Is there a way to check the member has access to a certain page, based on their sign up date (I have set in Woo Memberships that pages should only display after X days)??    For context - I'm creating a menu that only displays the pages they currently have access to.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this helps but here is my take on it. I first go through all of the users active membership and then I check the content $rules to see if the restricted plans are a part of the users membership plans (in_array)

```
function can_user_access_content($user_id,$post_id){
    //check if there's a force public on this content    
    if(get_post_meta($post_id,'_wc_memberships_force_public',true)=='yes') return true;
    $args = array( 'status' => array( 'active' ));
    $plans = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args );
    $user_plans = array();
    foreach($plans as $plan){
        array_push($user_plans,$plan->plan_id);
    }
    $rules = wc_memberships()->get_rules_instance()->get_post_content_restriction_rules( $post_id );

    foreach($rules as $rule){
        if(in_array($rule->get_membership_plan_id(), $user_plans)){
            return true;
        }
    }       
    return false;
}
```

Usage would be something like:

```
if(can_user_access_content(get_current_user_id(),$post->ID)){
    //do whatever here
}
```

Comment: I added in if the content is resticted at all: 
`function can_user_access_content($user_id,$post_id){
    //Check if this is restricted at all
    if(wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted($post_id) === false ) return true;  
   
}`

Answer (score 4):

I'm dealing with the same issue at [StoryMoment.com](http://storymoment.com) (we produce audio + eBook story series for kids).

This is how I've dealt with it.  I use the following in a page template to show or hide page elements based on access.  The `wc_memberships_view_delayed_post_content` would change based on the type of content.

You can see the other options in the file:

class-wc-memberships-capabilities.php

```
<?php 

$has_access = current_user_can( 'wc_memberships_view_delayed_post_content', $post->ID );

if ($has_access) {

//do something

} else {

//do something else

}

?>
```

Comment: Agreed. This is super simple and works perfectly. Just wondered how / if it's possible to add the Memberships built in "restricted content" message to the `else` section?