# WooCoomerce Membership - administrator has no current membership

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to integrate WooCommerce Memberships with some custom Advanced Custom Fields code and a Timber/Twig Wordpress set up. I found a [good function here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39715701/1397704) for checking if a user can access the content. Unfortunately I came across some difficulties when my administrator role didn't even have access. In my debugging I found that when calling `wc_memberships_get_user_memberships` with the current user ID, it would return NULL on my administrator user. I've since added a check to see if the user is a shop_manager or administrator and return true always for them.

```
function can_user_access_content($user_id,$post_id){

    // bail if Memberships isn't active
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_memberships' ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    $user = get_user_by('id',$user_id);
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) || in_array( 'shop_manager', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        //The user has the "administrator" or "shop manager" role
        return true;
    }

    //check if there's a force public on this content
    if(get_post_meta($post_id,'_wc_memberships_force_public',true)=='yes') return true;

    $args = array( 'status' => array( 'active' ));

    $plans = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args );

    $user_plans = array();

    foreach($plans as $plan){
        array_push($user_plans,$plan->plan_id);
    }
    $rules = wc_memberships()->get_rules_instance()->get_post_content_restriction_rules( $post_id );

    if(!count($rules)) {
        return true;
    }

    foreach($rules as $rule){
        if(in_array($rule->get_membership_plan_id(), $user_plans)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this a correct way to achieve this? I also am struggling on how to find a way to retrieve the appropriate "Content unavailable" message for the page/post/product to display. I am falling back to showing the regular post content if the content is restricted, which would normally have the messages filtered in my WC Memberships, but this doesn't appear to always work. Would love something a little more foolproof.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin already provides a function for this:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-function-reference/#wc_memberships_is_product_viewing_restricted

```
function wc_memberships_is_product_viewing_restricted( $post_id = null )
```

And it seems they have already handled the administrator logic because in the [FAQ](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-faq/#section-16), they stated that:

> As an administrator (or shop manager) user on your site, no content
>   will be restricted to you so that you can easily manage your site.

Comment: Thanks TurtleTread - this function actually only tells you if the product has any restrictions whatsoever - not if the current user is actually allowed to view it - we are somewhat expected to check that ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted WooCoomerce devs directly, and was given this response:

> Your approach looks good to me. Unfortunately you are correct, there
>   isn't a built in public function for checking if the the current
>   content is accessible to the current user. It would need to be written
>   as a custom function as you have done here.
>
> There may be other approaches to this with a combination of
>   `wc_memberships_get_user_memberships()` and
>   `wc_memberships_is_user_active_member()`, but the approach you have
>   taken looks ok to me.

So the above approach seems ok.